# Access Validation Code with multiple IF Statements

Tags: validation, ms-access

Good Evening, I am having an issue with setting up validation standards in my access database code. I want to make sure the first 4 digits match what is required for the entity I am attempting to add to a table. If it is once code it works but I have multiple it only checks the first validation by using Or.

```
    Select Case Me.txtEntityCodes
Case "UMMC"
If Not txtInforDepartment.Value Like "2010*" Or txtInforDepartment.Value Like "9999*" Then
MsgBox "Invalid Infor Department Code"
Cancel = True
Exit Sub

End If
End Select
```

Comment: _I want to make sure the first 4 digits match what is required for the entity_ so what four digits match what is required for the entity?

Comment: I believe that you simply need another `Not` after the `Or`? ... `... Or Not txtInforDepartment.Value Like "9999*"`